# Kendo UI combo box truncate initial space for values

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

**How can we display initial space for combo box value?** e.g.

```
“World”
“  America”
“     Washington”
```

When I am trying Kendo ui combo box, it is automatically removing space and displaying it like:

```
“World”
“America”
“Washinton”
```

A working example would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not specific to Kendo UI; white space gets collapsed in HTML.

You could use CSS:

```
.whitespace {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Then create your widget with a template (or apply the class to the `.km-animation-container` element which wraps the options):

```
var data = [{
    text: "Item1",
    value: "1"
}, {
    text: "   Item2",
    value: "2"
}, {
    text: "                  Item3",
    value: "3"
}];

$("#input").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data,
    template: "<span class='whitespace'> #= data.text # </span>",
    // if you want the display value to show the white space as well, 
    // you can additionally use a value template:
    valueTemplate: "<span class='whitespace'> #= data.text # </span>"
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/M5qE4/))

Comment: Hi Lars,I have another question here. I am using Kendo combo box inside the kendo grid and facing same problem. I have tried to use code same way but instead it is showing undefined as value. I have same kind of kendo combo box having value countryId, countryName and CurrencyInfo but I have to set value as CurrencyId and text as countryName. Could you please help me here?